# Unable to reload the same page after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript

I'm making a login page where if the email address already exists i want to stay on the same page and prompt the user that the email address already exists.
Here is the function which is the onClick function that will be called when the button is clicked

```
function login() {

    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pword = document.getElementById("pword").value;
    var confpwd = document.getElementById("confpwd").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var t = 1;

    if (t.toString() !== '0') {
        var er = "Email-id already exists";
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("nemail").value = er;
        document.getElementById("username").value = username;
        document.getElementById("pword").value = "";
        document.getElementById("confpwd").value = "";
        document.getElementById("fname").value = fname;
        document.getElementById("lname").value = lname;
        document.getElementById("gender").value = gender;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify what your actual question is.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass a function to the `<form onsubmit="return login()">`. The login function must return `true` if you want to submit and `false` otherwise. See this answer for more details: [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Working codepen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/YZqwLO

Comment: When not specified, the `event` parameter is actually assumed by most browsers. **EDIT:** Correction, it's IE and Chrome. Firefox does not seem to abide. (See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/0dbwLehc/) for a demo.)

Comment: Nice, I did not know that. Thanks!

Comment: When i'm doing that i'm getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.get1.onreadystatechange

Comment: @Santi..I use chrome but still getting this problem

Comment: @aeshna It means you are not passing the event in the onClick function. Your html should look likes this `onSubmit="login(this)"`.

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas i'm passing it for the button i.e. onclick="login(this)"; as i have two more buttons for different functions

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas but along with loading the same page i want to set some value in the input field as i have done in my code.If i do this then i wont be able to set value and prompt the client that the email id already exists

Comment: @aeshna you can update the value in the `login()` function before returning false. The page is not reloaded so the value will be updated.

Comment: But i have to use 3 buttons.One to registor the user and 2 for other functions.And for registor button i'm writing this function

Comment: @aeshna since form can have only one action when it's submitted, writing it on the `form` tag works as expected. You can do this with `onclick` as well. See this pen with all examples: http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/YZqwLO

Comment: This is my button  <input type="submit" name="Signup" value="Signup" style="width:100px;text-align: center;height:40px;" onclick="login(this);">             I tried return false or event.preventDefault().Nothing seems to work.Even when i'm using just onclick="login();",It does not work

Comment: var url="#";
            window.location.href =url;
            window.location.replace(url); This is working

Comment: @aeshna please create a codepen / plunker / jsfiddle so I can inspect it.

Comment: event.preventDefault() is working when i'm putting it just after the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your code is setup to submit. You may just need to insert a return when the code realizes the email address is a duplicate. Something along this path might help prevent the page from moving forward.

```
if (ListOfExistingEmails.indexof(email) > 0 ) return false;
```